# Replace if else statement with a single method containing a conditiion

Tags: c#

I am still learning C# but I've been on annual leave and I have come back to work and seen this piece of code my senior has left me before he went on his annual leave:

```
public string GetBasketTotalPrice(string basketLocation)
{
    var basketTotalPrice = _driver.FindElements(CommonPageElements.BasketTotalPrice);
    if (basketLocation.ToLower() == "top")
        return basketTotalPrice[0].Text.Replace("£", "");
    else
        return basketTotalPrice[1].Text.Replace("£", "");           

}

private int GetElementIndexForBasketLocation(string basketLocation)
{
    return basketLocation == "top" ? 0 : 1;
}
```

I am assuming instead of using the if else statement, he wants me to use his new method of GetElementIndexForBasketLocation.

My question is simply how to implement this change?

Thanks

Comment: `var index = GetElementIndexForBasketLocation(basketLocation.ToLower()); return basketTotalPrice[index].Text.Replace("£", "");`

Comment: Hint: how does 0 or 1 returned from `GetElementIndex...` relate to basketTotalPrice? No *new* numbers were added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you're looking for, but you can rework the code something like this:

```
    public string GetBasketTotalPrice(string basketLocation)
    {
        var basketTotalPrice = _driver.FindElements(CommonPageElements.BasketTotalPrice);
        int index = GetElementIndexForBasketLocation(basketLocation);
        return basketTotalPrice[index].Text.Replace("£", "");          
    }

    private int GetElementIndexForBasketLocation(string basketLocation)
    {
        return basketLocation.ToLower() == "top" ? 0 : 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the method he provided you isn't calling `ToLower()`, leaving it to the client to do that work, which could lead to mistakes down the road.

Also, you might consider using `string.Equals` with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead of `ToLower`.

And it might be a good idea to add a null check before trying to call a method on the string, so you can throw an `ArgumentNullException` instead of the `NullReferenceException` that the current code will throw.

```
public string GetBasketTotalPrice(string basketLocation)
{
    var basketTotalPrice = _driver.FindElements(CommonPageElements.BasketTotalPrice);

    return basketTotalPrice[GetElementIndexForBasketLocation(basketLocation)]
        .Text.Replace("£", "");
}

private int GetElementIndexForBasketLocation(string basketLocation)
{
    if (basketLocation == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(basketLocation));
    return basketLocation.Equals("top", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 0 : 1;
}
```